# how to get the V and I bold in a formula in a subsection

Tags: math-mode, bold, bm

this is the code

```
\subsection{$V_\text{GS}$ regelt $I_\text{D}$}
```

the V and I are not bold
when i try this with the `bm` package , i get an error

```
\subsection{$\bm{V}_\text{GS}$ regelt $I_\text{D}$}
\subsection{$\bm{V_\text{GS}}$ regelt $I_\text{D}$}
```

so I'm stuck with this  (V and I not bold)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `\text` for the use case at hand; use `\mathrm` instead, and place braces around the subscript terms.

To render both `V_{\mathrm{GS}}` and `$I_{\mathrm{D}}$` in **bold**, issue the instruction `\boldmath` at the start of the argument of `\subsection`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % optional

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{8}  % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{2}
\stepcounter{subsection}

\subsection{\boldmath $V_{\mathrm{GS}}$ regelt $I_{\mathrm{D}}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg -- Good catch! Thanks for the edits.